# Python dictionary comprehension - unhashable type: dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to perform below operations:

- iterate over a list of dictionary [{},{}]

  - call a transform function which transforms each dictionary, which returns a dictionary.

    - Here key and values are not static, but dataframe name and dataframe value. So dictionary may have one ore more key-value pair.
  - which I would need to store in a final dictionary

Expected : expected data would be a dictionary:

```
{"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2", "key3":"val3"} # ... in actual, the key would be dataframe name, value would be dataframe value
```

Simplified Use case:

```
dictname = [{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"},{"key3":"value3"}] # input list of dictionary

def transform(each):
    return each # to oversimplify, this would be a dictionary with one or more keys with transformations.

final = {transform(each) for each in dictname}
final
```

went over other related threads on the issue, could not figure out as how to handle the specific case. Could anyone please guide?e

Comment: Must `transform` return a dict? Why not just return the new value? The key is determined by the input.

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `{{...} for .. in ..}`, so you have a *set comprehension* that you're trying to put dicts into. Why not simply `{k: 'new_value' for k in dictname}`? Do you *need* to involve that function call?

Comment: @timgeb - yes, update the question.

Comment: @user16798185 well then the chainmap solution should do

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong in your code.

The dict comprehension is as follows: `{key: value, for key, value in something that outputs two things}`. In your case `transform_each` outputs a dict. So fixing this we obtain:

```
dictname = {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"} # input dictionary
def transform(each):
    return {each: "new_value"}
final = {key: transform(each) for key, each in dictname.items()}
final  # {'key1': {'val1': 'new_value'}, 'key2': {'val2': 'new_value'}}
```

This is not what you want. You need to change only the value of the dict. That is the second thing wrong: Your function must output a value, not a dict. Otherwise, as seen, you got a dict of dicts. You can fix it as follows:

```
dictname = {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"} # input dictionary

def transform(each):
    return "new_value"


final = {key: transform(each) for key,  each in dictname.items()}
final  # {'key1': 'new_value', 'key2': 'new_value'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define transform as

```
def transform(each):
    return <the new value>
```

and then use

```
result = {k: transform(k) for k in dictname}
```

If you cannot update `transform` use

```
from collections import ChainMap
result = dict(ChainMap(*(transform(k) for k in dictname)))
```

Comment: apologies for not updating the complete details, please can you take a look at updated question with complete details.

Answer (score 0):

This is an updated answer for the updated question.  I think the following should do what you want:

```
dictname = [{"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"}, {"key3":"val3"}]

def transform(each):
    return each

final = {k:v for d in dictname for k, v in transform(d).items()}
```

The `transform` function takes one of the dictionaries as an argument, and returns a dictionary.  The returned dictionaries from all the calls to `transform` are combined into the top-level dictionary `final`.

The example above defined `final` to be:

```
{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val3'}
```

In this example, `transform` merely returns the `dict` that was passed to it, but it could return any `dict` you want.

Comment: apologies for not updating the complete details, please can you take a look at updated question with complete details.

Comment: @user16798185 Ok, I posted a completely new answer based on my understanding of the updated question.  See if that does what you want.